# Article rich cards data not show up in Google Console

Tags: google-search-console, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I have implemented `NewsArticle` rich card data on a company blog like this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": "1",
          "item": {
            "@type": "Article",
            "headline": "Jak dodać menadżera do kanału YouTube?",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "https://websoul.pl/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/youtube_1500966468-728x728.png",
                "height": 728,
                "width": 728
              },
            "datePublished": "2017-07-25T08:08:24+00:00",
            "dateModified": "2017-08-11T08:40:52+00:00",
            "author": {
                "@type": "Person",
                "name": "Tomasz Smykowski"
              },
            "publisher": {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "Websoul",
                "logo": {
                  "@type": "ImageObject",
                  "url": "https://websoul.pl/richpublishericon60x600.png",
                  "width": 600,
                  "height": 60
                  }
                },
            "description": "Jak dodać menadżera do kanału na YouTube? O tym jak dać innej osobie dostęp do kanału dowiesz się z tego artykułu. Czytaj dalej&#8230;",
            "url": "https://websoul.pl/blog/jak-dodac-menadzera-do-kanalu-youtube",  
            "name": "Jak dodać menadżera do kanału YouTube?"
            }
          }
        ,{
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": "1",
          "item": {
            "@type": "Article",
            "headline": "Jak zaakceptować dostęp do konta Facebook Ads i Google Adwords",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "https://websoul.pl/blog/wp-conten.....
```

I validated it with Google validator and I have an error: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=pl#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsoul.pl%2Fblog%2F

Stating that all URLs should point to the same page. But as I can see all URLs point to the same page in fact.

I have submitted the website to Google index. I know it is indexed because I have also implemented AMP and it's working now.

But rich cards does not show up in Google Console. What to do so that my rich cards show up in Google Console?

Comment: My website is https://israel-escorts.com/. Which are kind of rich cards can be used on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get a carousel rich card, there are some issues with what you have defined.

First issue is that your page is a summary page with links to the articles. You will need to define them as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings under the **Summary page + multiple full details pages** heading.

On the summary page, you need to define structured data as a simplified ItemList. Make sure you increment the position for each Item.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":"ItemList",
  "itemListElement":[
    {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":1,
      "url":"http://example.com/desserts/apple-pie"
    },
    {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":2,
      "url":"http://example.com/desserts/cherry-pie"
    },
    {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":3,
      "url":"http://example.com/desserts/blueberry-pie"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

On the linked article pages you need to define structured data as an article.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://google.com/article"
  },
  "headline": "Article headline",
  "image": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg",
    "height": 800,
    "width": 800
  },
  "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
  "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
   "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Google",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg",
      "width": 600,
      "height": 60
    }
  },
  "description": "A most wonderful article"
}
</script>
```